# R readline, issues with User Input

Tags: r, readline

1

Firstly my issue is when sourcing a script, if that contains a readline call, the input in console is attached to the prompt

eg

sourcefile <- readline(prompt="Enter csv file name for FUND DATA, 2nd column price data\n")

in the console I type in equil, it appears as/this is where I'm typing

[Inputting looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWQjP.png)

After hitting enter, this then indents with \n. Notice how equil.. is now on the next line. Then for next readline I am again inputting with 0 space between my input and the prompt.

This is super unreadable/awkward. Is it possible to input for readlines on it's own line for readability? ie to have the user typing on the next line like it is after pressing enter

[Output then indents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtJtf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sourcefile <- readline(prompt=cat("Enter csv file name for FUND DATA, 2nd column price data\n"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for